# Write an application that inputs three integers from the user and displays the sum, average, product, smallest and largest of the numbers

Tags: java

I'm getting the sum, average and the product. The real difficulty I am facing is with the smallest and the largest number.

I can do it with two numbers, but three numbers is not making any sense to me. Ask me if my question isn't clear or if its not making sense.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// exercise 2.17
public class ArithmeticSmallestLargest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int sum;
        int average;
        int product;
        double largest

        System.out.print("Enter First Integer: ");
        num1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Second Integer: ");
        num2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Third Integer: ");
        num3 = input.nextInt();

        sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
        average = sum / 3;
        product = num1 * num2 * num3;


        if (largest =num1 > num2 & num2 > num3)

        System.out.println(sum);

        System.out.println(average);

        System.out.println(product);

        System.out.println("The biggest number is " + largest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Work on your logic to compute the largest number.

Comment: I think you would do well to read this guideline: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: This will be closed unless you show some real effort and be clear about the actual problem that you're facing.

Comment: @ShairyarShafqat - please do provide the code you used for getting largest/smallest number for two inputs. Then we can lead you to the solution.

Comment: What's so weird about finding the largest and the smallest number out of a set of three? Your exercise simply asks you to *sort* instead of just comparing two numbers.

Comment: it is not a home work question, i am trying to learn java on my own and thought i could get some help from experienced programmers. P.S i am using the JH2P, 9th edition.

Comment: @ShairyarShafqat - please provide the code you used for finding the larges/smallest of two inputs. (you can edit your question to add more info). Then we can lead you to the solution for three.
It's not that hard - if you can compare two, why can't you compare three?

Comment: @MichałSchielmann thanks a lot buddy, I actually got it myself. Perseverance prevails. if i have any questions in the future, i will be more elaborate. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// exercise 2.17
public class ArithmeticSmallestLargest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int sum;
        int average;
        int product;
        int largest;
        int smallest;

        System.out.print("Enter First Integer: ");
        num1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Second Integer: ");
        num2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Third Integer: ");
        num3 = input.nextInt();

        sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
        average = sum / 3;
        product = num1 * num2 * num3;

        largest = num1;
        smallest = num1;

        if(num2 > largest)
            largest = num2;

        if(num3 > largest)
            largest = num3;

        if(num2 < smallest)
            smallest = num2;

        if (num3 < smallest)
            smallest = num3;

        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);

        System.out.println("The average is " + average);

        System.out.println("The product is " + product);

        System.out.println("Largest of three integers is " + largest + " and the smallest is "+ smallest + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: good for you! Don't forget to accept your answer if it solves the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// exercise 2.17
public class ArithmeticSmallestLargest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int sum;
        int average;
        int product;
        int largest;
        int smallest;

        System.out.print("Enter First Integer: ");
        num1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Second Integer: ");
        num2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Third Integer: ");
        num3 = input.nextInt();

        sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
        average = sum / 3;
        product = num1 * num2 * num3;

        largest = num1;
        smallest = num1;

        if(num2 > largest)
            largest = num2;

        if(num3 > largest)
            largest = num3;

        if(num2 < smallest)
            smallest = num2;

        if (num3 < smallest)
            smallest = num3;

        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);

        System.out.println("The average is " + average);

        System.out.println("The product is " + product);

        System.out.println("Largest of three integers is " + largest + " and the smallest is "+ smallest + ".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArithmeticSmallestLargest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int sum;
        int average;
        int product;
        int largest;
        int smallest;

        System.out.print("Enter First Integer: ");

        num1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Second Integer: ");
        num2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Third Integer: ");
        num3 = input.nextInt();

        sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
        average = sum / 3;
        product = num1 * num2 * num3;
        largest = num1;
        smallest = num1;

        if(num2 > largest)
            largest = num2;

        if(num3 > largest)
            largest = num3;

        if(num2 < smallest)
            smallest = num2;

        if (num3 < smallest)
            smallest = num3;

        System.out.printf("The sum is %d%n " ,  sum);

        System.out.printf("The average is %d%n " ,  average);

        System.out.printf("The product is %d%n " , product);

        System.out.printf("Largest of three integers is %d%n " , largest);  

        System.out.printf("Smallest of three integers is %d%n " , smallest);
    }
}
```

Answer is given below:

Enter First Integer: 60
Enter Second Integer: 90
Enter Third Integer: 30

The sum is 180
 The average is 60
 The product is 162000
 Largest of three integers is 90
 Smallest of three integers is 30

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.