# Write a java program that inputs four doubles and displays the average of the numbers in two lines of output

Tags: java, casting, double

Example:

Input

```
4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0
```

Output

```
Average of { 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0 } is 4.0
```

I've referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675043/write-an-application-that-inputs-three-integers-from-the-user-and-displays-the-s) and wouldn't have a problem replicating that on my own, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it all in 1-2 lines of output. I was thinking there would be a line that inputs fourNumbers as a double using the Scanner Keyboard function, and then a subsequent int = (int) fourNumbers -- for each of the four, but there'd need to be something that locates one to three character spaces, to store each of the four numbers using separate identifiers (e.g. n1, n2, n3, n4), before outputting their average.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My current code is below but there's a problem with my use of the substring command/function.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Avg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double numbers;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        numbers = keyboard.nextInt();
        int n1 = (int) numbers.substring(0,3);
        int n2 = (int) numbers.substring(3,6);
        int n3 = (int) numbers.substring(6,9);
        int n4 = (int) numbers.substring(9,12);
        int average = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4)/4;
        System.out.println("Average of { " + n1 + ", " + n2 + ", "+ n3 + ", "+ n4 + " } is " + average);

        //TODO

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you also have a question that fits the requirements of SO?

Comment: Did I get it right that you want to know how to output 4 numbers on 1 line? Did you try something? Did you "replicate" and - more importantly - _understand_ the code you linked?

Comment: SO is not a free homework service, nor is it a forum for getting casual comments on homework problems.  If you have attempted some actual code, but you are stuck, then share it with us.

Comment: Sorry, here's my code. I'm not sure if I'm on the right track with the substring idea.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Avg {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  double numbers;
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  numbers = keyboard.nextInt();
  int n1 = (int) numbers.substring(0,3);
  int n2 = (int) numbers.substring(3,6);
  int n3 = (int) numbers.substring(6,9);
  int n4 = (int) numbers.substring(9,12);
  int average = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4)/4;
  System.out.println("Average of { " + n1 + ", " + n2 + ", "+ n3 + ", "+ n4 + " } is " + average);
  
 }
}

Comment: @studious1905 paste the code in the question, with proper formatting, instead of pasting it in the comments

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new to the site.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need doubles, not ints. So declare `n1`, `n2` to have type `double` (you may also want to rename them into `d1`, `d2`, etc., up to you). Don’t use `keyboard.nextInt()`, but `keyboard.nextDouble()`. Also declare `average` a `double`.

As you seem to have discovered, a `double` doesn’t have a `substring` method (in fact it has no methods at all). Instead, read each double from the keyboard separately:

```
    double n1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
    double n2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

(Also, your attempt at taking substrings would fail if I entered longer double values like 216.9875).

If you are performing the changes I suggest correctly, I would expect your program to work.

Answer (score 1):

**First Problem** : `substring` is a method in the `String` class. You can't call it on a *primitive data type* like a `double`.

**Second Problem** : You don't need `substring` to find the average of numbers. `substring` is used to extract a `String` from another `String`

You just need to **find the average** of 4 `double` values. Here is how you can do it :

1. Make A **Scanner Object** ``
2. Take input using `obj.nextDouble()` 4 times,  and assign those to the four `double`s
3. Calculate the average of those `double`s
4. Print it out

Comment: I honestly don’t think you are helping the original poster by writing all of the code for him or her. S/he is supposed to learn by writing his or her own code. I know you were just trying to be helpful. I suggest that you can be even more helpful by just pointing out the problems the way you do, and then describing the solution in English rather than Java.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for the advice. Just edited the answer.